# updating random dates to a single column (dates repeates)

Tags: sql, oracle, random, checksum, newid

Okay, first I identify the date integer for the particular date, onwards from which i need to update the random values into the `dpm_dateto` column :

Query :

```
select to_char(to_date('15/05/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'J') from dual;
```

Result:

```
2456428
```

Now, I try to update the `dpm_dateto` column using the query below:

```
update t_dailypm
set dpm_dateto = 
     (select to_date(trunc(dbms_random.value(2456428,2456428+76)), 'J') from dual)
where dpm_loc = 'P2' and dpm_department like '%IN%';
```

Result:

```
900 rows updated.
```

But, the problem is that each distinct value in `dpm_dateto` column is updated with the same date. I can't get my head around this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a subquery.

Just set=your_expression, like in the below example.
Oracle optimises the subquery and evaluates it only once, but the expression will be evaluated for each row:

```
create table xyz(
  abc date
);

insert into xyz
select sysdate from dual
connect by level < 6;

select * from xyz;

ABC    
--------
13/07/17 
13/07/17 
13/07/17 
13/07/17 
13/07/17
```

and now:

```
update xyz set abc = to_date(trunc(dbms_random.value(2456428,2456428+76)), 'J');

select * from xyz;

ABC    
--------
13/06/14 
13/07/23 
13/07/26 
13/06/24 
13/07/10
```

Comment: Thanks for the update kordirko..I just removed the subquery and voila!!...thanks again!

Comment: P.S. - Replaced the select(to_date(trunc... with simple to_date(trunc.. construct and it updated without optimization.